# Barren area inside a polygon

Tags: polygon

I was trying to create a polygon with a barren area inside, is there any way I can edit a polygon to create an excepted area?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a donut hole in your polygon? If so, [ESRI provides this guide](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-new-donut-holes-and-island-polygons.htm).
From ESRI:

> - Click a polygon feature template in the Create Features window.
> - Click a construction tool and method and digitize the outer boundary of the    polygon, without finishing the sketch.
> - Hold down the SHIFT key and click, or right-click and click Finish Part.
> - Click inside the polygon and sketch the inner boundary.
> - If you are creating a donut polygon, finish the sketch.
> - To create an island, finish the part and create another sketch inside the hole, then finish the sketch.